# Cross Correlation Techniques for Time Series Data

Tags: time-series, correlation, cross-correlation

I am working with time series data and am currently using cross correlation on my data. I can use different techniques like spearman, pearson, and kendall.

I was wondering if beyond that, there are any correlation techniques/methods including ML methods? Is it possible to do cross correlation with SVM or KNN?

Comment: Questions in the SE system are supposed to be narrow & 
concrete such that they can be given a definitively 
correct, factual answer in at  most a few paragraphs. 
This isn't a site for discussions or opinions.

Comment: I don't understand how my question cannot be given a correct factual answer. Do other statistical methods for cross correlation exist or no? This can be answered in a few sentences. I don't think opinions are valid answers to a question about if a method exists in statistics...

Comment: Please edit your question to tell us in detail what is your problem, your data, and your research goal!